# Swifty-JSON: unable to parse underscore

Tags: swift, parsing, swifty-json

There is a json file having **`____`** in a value like `"question": "11 ____________"`
Swifty-json is not able to parse and throwing error **`The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`** Is there any way to handle such situation?

JSON response -

```
"typingQuestionArray": [
          {
            "head": "Type the number name for the following number.",
            "question": "11 ____________",
            "imageLink": "",
            "correctAnswer": "eleven"
          }
]
```

Code Snippet -

```
if let path = getPath(name: chapterString){
    do {
           let data = try Data(contentsOf: path, options: .alwaysMapped)
           let json = try JSON(data: data)
           print(json)

        } catch let error {
            print("parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        } else {
            print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
```

**Note -  Do not doubt on JSON format and swift code. Only problem is `_____` in JSON.**

Screenshot for json validation -

[image]

Comment: show code and complete json

Comment: @Sh_Khan code updated. Complete json is very large, can not paste here but i already verified it on JSON Viewer. Please check

Comment: json surround with `{}` ?? also remove `, options: .alwaysMapped`

Comment: @Sh_Khan Json is valid. I only paste small chunks of json and already used . alwaysMapped

Comment: Dont doubt on json and swift code. Only problem is _____ in json

Comment: Rather than `error.localizedDescription` print only `error`. In most cases you get more detailed error information. And since Swift 3 `let error` in `catch` is redundant.

Comment: `print(error)` in `catch`

Comment: @Sh_Khan  - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 2396."

Comment: print the error itself. You Coding ey failed at some point. The property "error" will have the exact key which it failed at. Having a _____ in your String property is not an issue as you suspect.

Comment: ok after this line `let data = try Data(contentsOf: path, options: .alwaysMapped)`  do `let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8);print(str)` and attach the print

Comment: nothing work. Getting same "Unescaped control character around character 2396."

Comment: @Sh_Khan see the updated screenshot of json validation.

Comment: Since you know the exact position (2396) you can easily figure out what character causes the error.

Comment: Since copy/pasting the partial one you gave is being valid in JSONLint, I guess it's a invalid hidden char. Isolate it in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by replacing **`Tab`** to **`Whitespace`**.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using Swifty-JSON, but in case you are un hurry to make it work, it looks like the `JSONDecoder` gets the job done:

```
let data = """
{
    "head": "Type the number name for the following number.",
    "question": "11 ____________",
    "imageLink": "",
    "correctAnswer": "eleven"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

You did not post your struct, but I guess it looks like this:

```
struct Question: Codable {
    let head: String
    let question: String
    let imageLink: String
    let correctAnswer: String
}
```

Decoding:

```
let question = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Question.self, from: data)
```

Then one can print the question:

```
print (question)
// Output:
///Question(head: "Type the number name for the following number.", question: "11 ____________", imageLink: "", correctAnswer: "eleven")
```

In case you do not have interest in the solution with `JSONDecoder`, let me know and I will gladly delete this answer.